# Symfony2 Repositories and custom joins

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Ok i have a couple of tables in a database that I CAN NOT change the the structure to. That being said what I am trying to accomplish is to have a controller interact with the entities, do a custom join and return the results.

MORE DETAILS:

1st table has id, username

2nd table has user_id, stat1, stat2, stat3

what i want is to search for all users in table 1 joining table 2. I can do this with straight MySQL pretty easy but i want to know how to do it the symfony way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Doctrine where to find each piece of information so that it can load all the properties every time you instantiate a new User object. In other words, you need to add custom Doctrine mapping information. Assuming you're adding your mapping information as inline annotations to your User's model class, the code would look something like this:

```
//in User.php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="first_table_name")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserStats")
     */
    protected $stats;

    //also define getters and setters for the above, of course
}



//in UserStats.php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="table_two_name")
 */
class UserStats
{
     /** 
      * I'm pretty sure doctrine will require that you add an Id column to table_two, 
      * which is what this is. If you can't add an Id, I'm not sure it'll work...
      * @ORM\Id 
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue 
      */
     protected $id;

     /** 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User") 
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
     protected $user;

     /** 
      * The below assumes your stats are strings. If not, change the type attribute.
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      */
     protected $stat1;

     /** 
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      */
     protected $stat2;

     /** 
      * @ORM\Column(type="string")
      */
     protected $stat3;

     //include appropriate getters/setters here too
}
```

Comment: wont adding "protected $stats;" to the user entity try and add a column on that table?

Comment: Not unless you tell it to.  D2 won't automatically change your database structure.  From what you described, $stats should actually be $stat and be a OneToOne relation.  In any event, you need to read through the D2 manual to see how things work.